# How use python on ipad?

Tags: python, ipad

Recently, I've found that the ipad can run python with a special python interpret. But editing the code on ipad is a terrible nightmare. So how can I push the python code which has been edited completely on PC into the ipad and run it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Python for IOS, the following should work, although I haven't yet tried it myself.

Email the program to your own e-mail account as text.  Then read the e-mail message on your iPad in any one of several e-mail applications.  Cut and paste the text from the e-mail message into the python editor.

Don't cut and paste the code into the interpreter.  Then you can't save it, at least not in the current version of Python for IOS.  Instead, click on the second icon on the bottom (I think that's the icon, my iPad is at home and I'm not home now), to open the editor.  You can save files from the editor using the menu button on the upper right; there's a "save" menu item that allows saving the code to a file on the iPad.

I'll be trying this tonight.  Sorry for posting this before trying it, but I'm not sure I'll return to this question later.  It 'should' work.  (Famous last words!)

Answer (score 18):

you may be interesting in https://www.pythonanywhere.com project.

I am using it on ipad too.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just running command-line Python, then you can edit it and/or upload it to a server and then run it from an iPad ssh terminal client. I know that's not the same as pushing it onto the iPad, and it requires a server and an internet connection, but it's the easiest way.

Otherwise, include a Python interpreter in your app and a UITextView that prints its outputs. Edit the code on your PC (or Mac, I guess), as a file in your Xcode project, and have the interpreter run that code and show the output in the UITextView.

Answer (score 3):

### Pythonista for Ipad: save a script from the web in the Ipad

Pythonista is a great app for python on the ipad. If you use a bluetooth keyboard it can be also easier to digit (I use the logitech keyboard and it's great).
Save it to your github repository (or any other site).
Go into pythonista and run this script (python 3):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os

file = "test_es1.py"
url = urlopen("https://formazione.github.io/" + file)
content = url.read()
p = ""
with open(file, "w") as new_file:
    content = content.decode("utf-8")
    print(content)
    new_file.write(content)
os.startfile(file)
```

Now, you have saved the file from you site to pythonista, you can open it from the app and run it.

Answer (score 2):

I use Python 2.7 for IOS and download source python files through iFunBox into /var/mobile/Applications/Python 2.7 for IOS/Documents/User Scripts. Nevertheless I can't recommend this application as it's quite buggy and very slow when editing code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the eclipse Che editor on Codenvy.com

[Codenvy Websife](https://codenvy.com/)

It's a browser-based IDE and can be used from any device that has a web browser.